# acpi and function keys

Tags: acpi, backlight

Good day to all,

**No matter what I try, I just can't seem to get *all* of my function keys working.**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

With the aforementioned setting, all function keys except volume control (mute, increase, decrease) and wifi control work.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=native"
```

With the aforementioned setting, all function keys except brightness control (increase, decrease) work. However, I can modify brightness with xbacklight or graphically through brightness & lock.

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
intel_backlight
```

Is there any acpi or other option I am missing that would give me complete functionality of my function keys? I have tried various options to no avail, such as acpi_backlight=vendor, acpi_osi=Linux, and acpi_osi=Windows, and various combinations thereof.

---

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with an i5 6200U, no dedicated graphics.

Comment: It sounds that your problem matches point two from this [site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight). Perhaps it might help to look at this [site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting). If not please collect information for report as described in the second link.